# How convert a folder to a signle file without compression and extra hard space

Tags: hard-drive, ftp, compression

I have a server in another country with 5GB free space.
In this server there is a folder with 60GB size.
Problem is download this folder via ftp or http.
In my area http is faster than ftp.
As you know internet download manager can not download folders directly and it recognizes files only.
I can not compress such this folder because of it's size.
Also after bypassing compression time i have not enough space for this job.
iso conversion needs another 50GB size too.
How can i convert that folder to a single file without compression job and extra hard space & reverse back that file to a folder after download?

Comment: Why is "internet download manager" a factor in this? HTTP and FTP are both contingent on your actual link and if both are hosted from the same place with all things being equal (eg. rate limiting or something weird) both should download at the same rate. Why can't you login to your remote server and tar or gzip the folder?

Comment: This seems to be and X-Y problem. Why not use a different download manager?

Comment: @nannerpuss IDE is faster other that ftp clients.  Also i can not gzip or tar because of low space of my hard drive. Refer to my Q again.

Comment: @ChanganAuto What download manager can download a folder instead of file?

Comment: Dozens of them.

Comment: I am talking about download through http wire - Not FTP.

Comment: Me too. Dozens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither protocol alone supports downloading a folder as an archive and therefore your undertaking is not possible.

Many FTP or HTTP clients support the recursive download of all files within a folder though.

If you have the ability to run a program on the server you can make (or run) a HTTP server which offers a zip file for each folder and creates the zip on-the-fly for your download.
This one looks pretty good for your needs: https://github.com/ViRb3/serve-zip